# SilverStripe Blog GridfieldConfig Lumberjack Sort

Tags: php, silverstripe

SSTR 3.1.16, Blog 2.3.0 and lumberjack as required by blog -> ~1.1

I don't know how I am supposed to alter the GridfieldConfig in the Blog module generated by Lumberjack.

here it's generated:
https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-blog/blob/master/code/model/Blog.php#L528

and overrides what is set here:
https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-lumberjack/blob/1.1/code/extensions/Lumberjack.php#L131

Since I didn't get how to modify without hacking it, I tried Injector like this:

```
<?php

class BlogInj extends Blog {
    public function getLumberjackGridFieldConfig() {
        $ljgfc = GridFieldConfig_Lumberjack::create();
        // $ljgfc->addComponent(new GridFieldOrderableRows('Sort'));
        // $ljgfc->getComponentByType("GridFieldPaginator")->setItemsPerPage(100);
        return $ljgfc;
    }
}

config.yml                            
Injector:
  Blog:
    class: BlogInj
```

This shows the GF with the options set (commented out above) but as soon as a getLumberjackGridFieldConfig function exists on BlogInj Blog throws an Error on save like:
Error at line 763 of .../framework/core/Object.php
https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-framework/blob/3.1/core/Object.php#L763

How am I supposed to modify Lumberjacks GF-Config in the first place? Or is Injector really what I should use an if so, what am I doing wrong?

Comment: can you get the backtrace of the error in your error log or when debugging the ajax request in e.g. firebug's network tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [Blog just returns a GridFieldConfig_BlogPost](https://github.com/silverstripe/silverstripe-blog/blob/master/code/model/Blog.php#L528) object you could try to subclass this instead.

```
class GridFieldConfig_MyBlogPost extends GridFieldConfig_BlogPost
{
    public function __construct($itemsPerPage = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($itemsPerPage);

        // do what you want...
    }
}
```

And in your config.yml

```
Injector:
  GridFieldConfig_BlogPost:
    class: GridFieldConfig_MyBlogPost
```

Comment: Works just fine. Thank you!